# Can't get integer value from EditText

Tags: java, android

I can't get integer value from `EdiText(edText)`. I don't know why this problem occurs. The part under `Catch` is executed instead of `Try`.

```
   public class Ybus_Activity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ybus);
        //Creating Linear Layout
        final LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        final LinearLayout main = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.android_main_layout);
        //Creating TextView
        TextView getData=new TextView(this);
        getData.setText("Enter the number of LineData : ");
        getData.setId(5);
        getData.setLayoutParams(params);
        main.addView(getData);
        //Creating EdiText
        final EditText edText = new EditText(this);
        edText.setId(3);
        edText.setLayoutParams(params);
        edText .setWidth(100);
        edText .setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
        edText .setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        edText .setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance());
        edText .setMaxLines(1);
        main.addView(edText );
        final String ed=edText.getText().toString();
        //Creating Button for displaying integer from edText
        Button bt = new Button(this);
        bt.setText("Click to enter Linedata");
        bt.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        main.addView(bt);
        final TextView text = new TextView(this);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        { 
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                int i = 0;
                try{
                    i =Integer.parseInt(ed);
                    text.setText(i);
                }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
                    text.setText("Value at TextView is not a valid integer");
                }
            }
        });
        main.addView(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: why u get text from edText in onCreate, should not it be in onClick method?

Comment: @pepela no it must be in onClick()...That was the mistake i did...And now solved...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can use a string to show at textview so you can do as follows

```
     bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        { 
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                String ed=edText.getText().toString(); 
                int i = 0;
                try{
                  i =Integer.parseInt(ed);
                 //setting value here
                 text.setText(String.valueof(i));
                 //or you can do like this
                 // text.setText(i+"");
                }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
                  text.setText("Value at TextView is not a valid integer");
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: i used this...but still getting error...that is catch statement "Value at TextView is not a valid integer"  is executing

Comment: yes sure... just you need to move String ed=edText.getText().toString(); line inside the OnClickListener of Button bt and also now when you are getting value parse it as an integer and than you already know that we can set a text only to textview so we are again converting it into string by doing String.valueof(i) or simply (i+"").

Answer (score 1):

Convert `int` to `String` for displaying your content into `TextView`. It's because of `setText(CharacterSequence)` has set `CharacterSequence`.

```
 text.setText(String.valueof(i));
```

Implement your Button click listener this way:

```
bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{  
public void onClick(View v) 
{
int i = 0;
try{
  String ed=edText.getText().toString(); 
  i =Integer.parseInt(ed);
  text.setText(String.valueOf(i);

}catch(NumberFormatException ex){
  text.setText("Value at TextView is not a valid integer");
  }
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Move this  `String ed=edText.getText().toString();`

```
bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{  
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    int i = 0;
    try{
      String ed=edText.getText().toString(); 
      i =Integer.parseInt(ed);
      text.setText(String.valueOf(i));
    }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
       e.printStacktrace();
    }
}
});
```

inside button click listener

Also `setText(int)`(i is a int value i) looks for a Resource with the id mentioned. If not found you get `ResourceNotFOundException`. Instead use `setText(CharacterSequence)` for which you need to use  `text.setText(String.valueOf(i));`

Answer (score 0):

This to string:

```
text.setText(i+"");
```

And get int value

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You change the line :

```
i =Integer.parseInt(ed);
text.setText(i);
```

to:

```
i = Integer.parseInt(edText.getText().toString());
text.setText(i+"");
```